# Internet Connection Sharing using routes

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, nat

#### Situation

I'm trying to share my Desktop's Internet connection to my Laptop.
Here is the layout of my network:

[image]

- I only control the green computers.
- The routes on the desktop are automatically and correctly set by DHCP and the OpenVPN client config file.
- I have access to all the orange networks on it.

#### Here's what I tried:

- using Windows Internet Connection Sharing, sharing `tap0` to `eth1` :
  Works for all orange networks except `172.16.0.0/12`
- using NET32 IP Router, internet from `tap0` and private on `eth1` :
  Same problem as I have to choose the interface that has internet access.
  I tried selecting both `eth0` and `eth1`, but it forces me to set them to static ip, which breaks everything because I need to be using DHCP on `172.16.0.0/12`.

#### Main question :

- Is there a way, on the desktop computer, to forward the packets from an interface to their destination, using the system's routes to choose the interface and gateway ?
- On a more general note, is there a reason not to do it by default ?

Comment: "Works for all orange networks except 176.16.0.0/12" - This network isn't in your diagram (which has 172.16.0.0/12). Which is correct?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, edited main post

Comment: `On a more general note, is there a reason not to do it by default`. 
Only complexity.  Why not also start a VPN from the laptop?

Comment: @V1rgul You still have another `176` in your post.

Comment: my bad, the typo was copy/pasted.  
@Hennes from my laptop to the openvpn server ?  
If I'm connecting to it through it, with the current configuration, I would not have access to `172.16.0.0/12`.  
If I'm connecting to it from `172.16.0.0/12` by bridging `eth0` and `eth1` it would work except the Company's switches only accept one IP per port, I have to have NAT on the Desktop :/

Answer (score -1):

it sounds  more like you need a packetshaper and a router with assignable v-lan ports. i suggest eBay for the packetshaper they can be managed from a laptop and once configured they are autonomous.
[packetshapers i recommend based on ease of deployment](https://www.bluecoat.com/products-and-solutions/wan-optimization-packetshaper)

[what im used to working with for switching](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/nexus-9000-series-switches/index.html)

[and this is something  more exacting to what your trying to do](http://netgear.com/business/products/switches/managed/m4100.aspx)

hope  this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do. I only manage the green computers and would like to do it in software on windows (I have 2 Ethernet interfaces on the desktop).
Thanks for the attention.